# Can't turn off Google Personal Search, the option isn't displayed

Tags: google-search

I'm trying to [turn off personal results in Google search](http://support.google.com/websearch/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2410479) but I can't find where the settings are.

I am directed to my Google account's Search Settings but the section I need - "Search plus Your World" - is not on my list of options.

How do I bring this up to disable the thing?

Comment: Are you sure its enabled on your account.  My understanding it was a rolling update.

Comment: Is there a source for that? Rolling from what date, recently?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not under "Search plus your world", it is under "Personal results".
Make sure you are signed into your Google account, go to www.google.com, click on the gear on the top right of the page, and select "Search settings".

[image]

Comment: Well I tried all that just now and guess what - it appears to be disabled - nothing doing.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, when I click under "Personal Results Search" with the On setting (which is the only logical place I can see to click to try and disable it, its sending me to a page that says this:

"
403. That’s an error.

We're sorry, but you do not have access to this page. That’s all we know.
"
If this is happening to you please let me know.